# How to trigger a Policy in Google Cloud Stackdriver via terminal (SDK or API)?

Tags: terminal, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-stackdriver

currently I am working one some ways to test the capabilities of Google Cloud Stackdriver and how to automate most of it.
During my tests, I have to create different policies and checks, but Google Cloud Platform needs a long time until it checks one policy and sends out a notification.
I know from my GCP exam, that the supported and best practice way to do test in Stackdriver is by triggering a policy as "dry run".

Unfortunately I can't find any documentation or commands in the Google Cloud SDK on how to call this dry run and test my policies - without waiting 15 minutes for the initial check.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Thanks to Sudarshan for raising a feature request to Google in [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186026191). Feel free to star the request to show interest and follow the progress.

---

I can't find any "manual trigger" for alerts in the [Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rpc/) description.

However, you should be able to manually [insert the timeseries data](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/create) on the API, with the data going as far back as you need (specifying the proper [intervals](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/TimeSeries#Point)) to force the policy to trigger.

Comment: For  manually triggering of alerts, you can file a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for Stackdriver Monitoring.

Comment: This is still not supported in Stackdriver Monitoring. I have filed for a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186026191). Please upvote

Comment: @SudarshanMurthy Thanks for raising the feature request. I've updated the answer with the link to give it more visibility.